# Append Multiple objects into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects of the structure coming from server response of iterated array object like as sample

```
array[1] ={
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "15"     
}
array[2] ={
    "ID": "456",
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Age": "18"     
}
array[n] ={

}
```

But now I want to append the array values if the condition age below 18 in the following structure of as iterated values of above  array
Expected Output:

```
{
    "Stud": [{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "15"
    }, {
        "ID": "456",
        "Name": "Sue",
        "Age": "18"
    },{n........
  }]
}
```

Comment: what is actually the difference between the two arrays?

Comment: Append to which array? make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = { "Stud" : [] };
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i].Age < 18) {
        output.Stud.push(array[i]);
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: May you explain the code you are showing, or why the OP should use it instead of different code?

Comment: whats OP ? 
i have 2 things 1st is array and 2nd is output object. 
and you want all record who are under age. so i use if under for loop. 
* i use reverse for loop coz it's fast than reg for loop.

Comment: @agravat.in  hi friend, `OP referring to the asker of the question. (Original Poster)`. What kiamlaluno said is you have to add some description , instead of posting only code.

Comment: hmm next time whenever i ans i will put some descriptions. i am new in stack-overflow.

Comment: @agravat.in  great.. go ahead all the best

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
var output = { "Stud" : array }; //existing 'array'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` to select objects with age less than or equal to 18.

```js
const response = [{
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "15"     
},{
    "ID": "456",
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Age": "18"     
},{
    "ID": "459",
    "Name": "Jaby",
    "Age": "20"     
}];

const result = response.filter(o => o.Age <= 18);
var output = {'stud' : result};
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate and check whether the age is < 18 or not. If so push that to another array.

```js
    var array = [];
    var array_below_18 = [];
    array[0] ={
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "15"     
    }
    array[1] ={
        "ID": "456",
        "Name": "Sue",
        "Age": "18"     
    }

    array[1] ={
        "ID": "456",
        "Name": "Sue",
        "Age": "14"     
    }

    for(i=0;i<array.length;++i){
       if(parseInt(array[i].Age)<18){
          array_below_18.push(array[i]);
       }
    }

    var final_object = {
        "Stud" : array_below_18
    }

    console.log(final_object);
```